# How do I install .NET Core 2.0 in Ubuntu i686 architectures?

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, x86-64, .net-core-2.0

How do I install .NET Core 2.0 in Ubuntu i386/i686/i86-64 architectures? All the links I found lead to amd-64 installations.

```
uname :
Linux XXX-virtual-machine 3.5.0-43-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 17:33:43 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Update:

I did try to install .NET Core in x86-x64 architectures. I followed the procedure from this link.https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxubuntu

In Step-1, I removed `"[arch=amd64]"` (also tried replacing with x86) and added it to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'`

Added the below repository manually to `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

```
 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-zesty-prod zesty main
```

(tried with `'deb https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-trusty-prod trusty main`' as welll)

In Step-2, after issuing the command, `sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.0` I got the error that no i86/i64 entry point found for the repositories.

```
 Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-zesty-prod/dists/zesty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-trusty-prod/dists/trusty/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

I then had to use a brand new amd64 Ubuntu machine to get .NET installed. In amd64 Ubuntu, just following the steps from the link above gives a seamless installation.

Comment: In my experience, amd-64 is a general term in ubuntu for any 64bits architecture. Go ahead, try, if you have any trouble post a question.

Comment: @Pac0 I believe this is correct. amd64 was a 64 bit architecture for x86 based chips designed by AMD. Intel's was ia64 which had a few issues and Intel then followed made their CPU's compatible with AMD's architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amd-64` or `amd64` in Ubuntu packages (and other Debian-based Linux flavors) **refers to any 64 bits  architecture**, even if you don't have an AMD processor.

This designation has started like that because AMD's design was the first 64bit design widely adopted. And on some systems like Ubuntu, the name reference had to be kept as is, unfortunately for some which are confused by the differences between systems.

For some historical reference, you can simply visit the [x86-64 Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), for a start.

Comment: That's because AMD were the first one to design a x86-64bit architecture. Intel is licencing x64 from AMD. Intel's EM64T architecture is just rebranded AMD64.

Comment: added more historical context to my answer.

Comment: _AMD's design was the first 64bit design widely adopted_ - that's kind of ambiguous. If you are talking about x86-64bit architecture then sure "AMD's design was the first 64bit design widely adopted" because it was the first x86-64bit **ever** (Intel's IA64 was not a x86 arch). If you are talking about any 64bit architecture then it's not true because there were non-x86 64bit architectures way before (Sun had theirs at least few years before AMD). My point is it's called AMD64 because it's designed by AMD.